# Node.js spawn multiple SQS listeners threads in one project

Tags: node.js, multithreading, amazon-web-services

I have a Node.js project that is consuming messages off AWS SQS (a message queue). I would like to spin up multiple consumers in the same project to keep up with the messages placed in the queue without having to create another Node.js instance.  Is it possible to do that with something like Fibers or another framework?  I'm basically trying to make the act of receiving messages multithreaded (competing consumers pattern).

Here's an example:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk'),
    nconf = require('nconf'),
    SQS_URL = process.env.SQS_SERVICES_EVENTS;

AWS.config.update({accessKeyId: nconf.get("accessKeyId"), secretAccessKey: nconf.get("secretAccessKey")});
AWS.config.update({region: nconf.get("region")});

// Initialize SQS
var sqs = new AWS.SQS();

// Params for SQS
var MAX_NUM_MSGS = nconf.get("sqs.max.messages");
var params = {
    QueueUrl: SQS_URL,
    MaxNumberOfMessages: MAX_NUM_MSGS,
    VisibilityTimeout: 30,
    WaitTimeSeconds: 20
};

exports.startSqsListener = setInterval(sqsListener, nconf.get("sqs.interval"));

// Make multi-threaded
function sqsListener() {
    sqs.receiveMessage(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            logger.error(err, err.stack);
        }
        if (data.Messages) {
            // do something with each message
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to process more messages simultaneously you could write an async function to implement the logic for "doing something with each message". As long as the messages don't need to be processed in sequential order, node will automatically queue up each async execution and run them concurrently.

```
sqs.receiveMessage(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        logger.error(err, err.stack);
    }
    if (data.Messages) {
        data.Messages.forEach(function(message) {
            processMessage(message, function(err) {
                //check for error, do something with it
            });
        });
    }
});

function processMessage(messageData, callback) {
    //move your processing here

    callback(); //or send error back, if needed
}
```

Comment: No I need to do it at a higher level than this. By this point, I've already received the message so processing that part is trivial. I basically want to set up multiple receivers so the calling function that calls the export `startSqsListener` could call it `n` number of times to spin up workers that will receive messages separately. It's the competing consumers EAI pattern I'm trying to implement.

Comment: If you want to run more of your listener functions, couldn't you simply call the `startSqsListener` function multiple times? Each call would execute the `setTimeout` function, generating another listener that executes on an interval. SQS will hide messages based on the `VisibilityTimeout`, so you'll receive a different batch of messages within each listener.

Comment: What I ended up doing is have the calling function call the exported function `n` number of times.  Since I have this export on `setInterval` it will continuously running looking for SQS messages. Thanks for some insight on this.

Comment: @occasl do you mind sharing it, i have the same issue. Thank you. Also did it help? How many messages does it handle for you now?